# Cider repl throws java.lang.IllegalAccessError: with-safe-transport does not exist

Tags: emacs, clojure, spacemacs, cider

cider seems to be throwing a weird exception when trying to eval anything (for example "(+ 1 2)" ). see below:

[image: cider error]
The project is nothing special, just 'lein new test-cider' that i made just to try this out.

my profiles.cljs only contains "lein-ancient" so nothing special there either.

the project.clj only contains clojure 1.8.0.

I'm using emacs(25.3.1) spacemacs(latest), on macOS(10.12.6).

emacs has no configs other then what spacemacs sets up.
spacemacs has ui related configs + parinfer

I'm new to emacs and cider, so i'm not sure what other info to give.

Can somebody help me out?

Cheers,

Boogie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a github issue for cider describing the problem and providing a workaround for this issue. but for some reason google did not get me there. google is off today

this is the issue:

https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/2092